# MariaDB SphinxSE not accepting weights parameter

Tags: mariadb, sphinx, sphinxsearch

If I try this query:

```
select * FROM sphinx.products where `query` = "test";
```

it works.  But if I try to give it weights it returns an error:

```
select * FROM sphinx.products where `query` = "test;sort=extended:@weight DESC;weights=3,1,1,1";
```

Fails with error:

```
Error in query (1430): There was a problem processing the query on the foreign data source.
Data source error: searchd error: invalid deprecated unordered_weight count 4 (expe
```

(Error reported by MariaDB gets truncated there, but I believe it says "expecting 0")

And:

```
select * FROM sphinx.products where `query` = "test;sort=extended:@weight DESC";
```

Fails with error:

```
Error in query (1430): There was a problem processing the query on the foreign data source.
Data source error: searchd error: index 'sku_products': sort-by attribute '@weight'
```

(Again, error returned by SphinxSearch gets truncated by MariaDB)

All the documentation I find about SphinxSE tells me to query the index this way, yet it does not work, but nobody in the Internet seem to have met this error since nobody is asking about this anywhere...

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the option `weights=` didn't work, but it accepted `fieldweights=sku,90,partnumber,30,barcode,20,name,10`.

(I.e., `fieldweights=<field1_name>,<field1_weight>,...`)

Results came ordered by weight even without specifying `sort=extended:@weight DESC`, so I dodged both errors and got what I needed.

Hope this helps anyone in the same situation.

Comment: The 'weights' option was removed around Sphinx 2.2.1 - see changelog: A.11. Version 2.2.1-beta, 13 nov 2013
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#rel221 - `fieldweights` is the replacement for `weights`

Comment: When working with SphinxQL directly and using that documentation as a guide you would know that fieldweights existed, but SphixSE is not the same thing as SphinxQL and all tutorials that I could find were using weights and were not completely clear about the relation between SphinxSE and SphinxQL.